# emgucv won't read video/image files, getting an System.NullReferenceException error

Tags: video, emgucv

Here is part of the code where I am getting the error;

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region Extract Model Face Detections From Video Clips

        var modelVideos = Directory.GetFiles(@"ModelsVideos\", "*.MOV");

        foreach (var modelVideo in modelVideos)
        {
            var capture = new Capture(modelVideo);

            var framesQueue = new Queue<Image<Gray, byte>>();

            capture.ImageGrabbed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                var currentFrame = capture.RetrieveGrayFrame();
                framesQueue.Enqueue(currentFrame);
            };
```

I tried many different formats and codecs, such as .mov, .avi, .mp4.
I also tried updating emgucv to version 3.0.
It won't even work when I try to read an image file. I also made sure I have all my binaries and .dll files. I saw all the solutions with opencv_ffmpeg300.dll and I made sure I have that as well.

This is the full error I am getting;

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll Additional information: Unable to create capture from ModelsVideos\video.MOV
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the full path to the videos folder just like the following

```
var modelVideos = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\ModelsVideos\", "*.MOV");//full path to the videos folder.
```